# Value from Select not showing up in input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

The select option is within a fieldset and uses AJAX to Post the data to a Mongodb. For some reason all the other values will show up in the DB except for the location option.

Below is the Jade code and JS for the function for adding it. This is my first project and not sure if I'm just missing something obvious or not.

Also, when I change the type to number for some inputs it invalidates everything and it posts and entry to the DB with no data attached to it. Any ideas?

```js
// Add User
function addUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Super basic validation - increase errorCount variable if any fields are blank
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('#addUser input').each(function(index, val) {
        if($(this).val() === '') { errorCount++; }
    });

    // Check and make sure errorCount's still at zero
    if(errorCount === 0) {

        // If it is, compile all user info into one object
        var newUser = {
            'Date_Entered': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputDate_Entered').val(),
            'First_Name': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputFirst_Name').val(),
            'Last_Name': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputLast_Name').val(),
            'Incident_Date': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputIncident_Date').val(),
            'Resoulution_Date': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputResolution_Date').val(),
            'Location': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputlocation').val(),
            'Damage': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputDamage').val(),
            'Cost': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputCost').val(),
            'Coupon': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputCoupon').val(),
            'Vehicle_Year': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputVehicle_Year').val(),
            'Make': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputMake').val(),
            'Resolution': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputResolution').val(),
            'Model': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputModel').val(),
            'Comments': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputComments').val(),
            'Claim_type': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputClaim_type').val(),
            'ManagersName': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputManagersName').val(),
            'Resolution_Date': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputResolution_Date').val(),
            'CouponQuantity': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputCouponQuantity').val(),
            'CouponType': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputCouponType').val(),
            'Address': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputAddress').val(),
            'City': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputCity').val(),
            'State': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputState').val(),
            'Zip': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputZip').val(),
            'Email': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputEmail').val(),
        }

        // Use AJAX to post the object to our adduser service
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: newUser,
            url: '/users/adduser',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function( response ) {

            // Check for successful (blank) response
            if (response.msg === '') {

                // Clear the form inputs
                $('#addUser fieldset input').val('');

                // Update the table
                populateTable();

            }
            else {

                // If something goes wrong, alert the error message that our service returned
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);

            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // If errorCount is more than 0, error out
        alert('Please fill in all fields');
        return false;
    }
};
```

```html
        // ADD USER
        h2 Add User
        #addUser
            fieldset
                input#inputDate_Entered(type='date', placeholder='Username')
                input#inputFirst_Name(type='text', placeholder='Email')
                br
                input#inputLast_Name(type='text', placeholder='Full Name')
                input#inputIncident_Date(type='date', placeholder='Age')
                br
                input#inputResolution_Date(type='date', placeholder='Location')
                p
                label
                  select#inputlocation(type='text', tabindex='#{tab_index++}')
                    option 11 North Mchenry
                    option 12 Ceres
                    option 13 Turlock
                    option 14 Briggsmore
                    option 15 Merced
                    option 16 Lodi
                    option 18 Dale Road
                    option 19 Oakdale
                    option 20 Riverbank
                    option 21 Atwater
                    option 22 Plaza
                    option 23 Manteca
                    option 24 South Mchenry
                    option 25 Tracy
                    option 26 University
                    option 27 Whitmore
                br
                input#inputDamage(type='text', placeholder='Damage Type')
                input#inputCost(type='text', placeholder='Cost')
                br
                input#inputCoupon(type='text', placeholder='Coupon')
                input#inputVehicle_Year(type='text', placeholder='Year')
                br
                input#inputMake(type='text', placeholder='Make')
                input#inputResolution(type='text', placeholder='Resolution')
                input#inputModel(type='text', placeholder='Model')
                input#inputComments(type='text', placeholder='Comments')
                br
                input#inputClaim_type(type='text', placeholder='Claim Type')
                input#inputManagersName(type='text', placeholder='Managers Name')
                br
                input#inputResolution_Date(type='text', placeholder='Resolved')
                input#inputCouponQuantity(type='text', placeholder='Coupon Quantity')
                br
                input#inputCouponType(type='text', placeholder='Coupon Type')
                input#inputAddress(type='text', placeholder='Address')
                br
                input#inputCity(type='text', placeholder='City')
                input#inputState(type='text', placeholder='State')
                br
                input#inputZip(type='text', placeholder='Zip')
                input#inputEmail(type='text', placeholder='Email')
                button#btnAddUser Add User
```

Comment: FYI, ID's are unique, something like `$('#addUser fieldset input#inputComments')` makes no sense at all, it should be just `$('#inputComments')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually the strange selectors, this

```
$('#addUser fieldset input#inputlocation')
```

does not match a select element, that would be

```
$('#addUser fieldset select#inputlocation')
```

but they are both wrong, it should be just

```
$('#inputlocation')
```

Comment: I guess that's one of the problems with following tutorials, works perfectly now, thank you very much. I've changed them all now.